# tags - code, code-compliance, building regulations

Tags: discussion

I just edited the tags on a question to change "code" to "code compliance" as it was the only question using that tag. Should code be a synonym of code compliance?

There are also several questions tagged "building regulations". It seems to me this is the same sort of thing as code-compliance and might be merged. However there is the twist that "code compliance" is US phraseology not used in the UK and "building regulations" is used in the UK (but also to a small extent in the US).

The description of code-compliance uses terms like federal and state in ways that are US specific, so there might be room for a separate tag that relates to non-US regulation/law that applies to the construction of homes and the wiring and plumbing etc.

If I asked a question about *UK* building regulations which tags should I use?

How about Aussies, Kiwis, Canadians, Indians etc?

Comment: I believe that [code] being a synonym of [code-compliance] is correct.  Re: [code-compliance] vs [building-regulations] -- I would agree that the two terms are functional equivalents, and I *believe* that they could be made synonyms; however, I'd have to take a much closer look.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you edited the only use of [code](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code) to use [code-compliance](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-compliance) then there's no need to create a synonym as that tag will have disappeared from the system.

When anyone asks a question and types "code" into the tags list they'll get "code-compliance" as a suggested tag so they should use that rather than recreate the "code" tag.

If it does reappear, then it would be the time to consider making it a synonym.

As to the other question about [code-compliance](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-compliance) vs [building-regulations](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building-regulations), that's now being discussed [here](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1339)