# Is [building-regulations] a generic tag? Can it be made UK-specific?

Tags: discussion, tag-wikis

I saw a [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/133286/what-type-of-guard-rail-is-needed-on-an-open-part-of-a-5-tread-stair) tagged [building-regulations](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building-regulations) today. I initially assumed that it was asking about the [UK Building Regulations](https://www.gov.uk/building-regulations-approval), a specific set of codes. I checked the tag info to make sure... but there's no tag info.

On meta I found [this unanswered question](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/tags-code-code-compliance-building-regulations) which says that *"building regulations" is used in the UK (but also to a small extent in the US)*.

Can I fill in the tag info and make it specific to UK Building Regs? Or is it a generic tag that US users want to be able to use?

If making it UK-only I think I would also need to:

- Change its name to UK-Building-Regulations
- Add wording that non-UK users should use {code-compliance}
- Go through all 79 questions currently tagged and re-tag any that are clearly not UK

Comment: Perhaps at the same time change the tag to [uk-building-regulations] to be absolutely clear?

Comment: I'd be reluctant to have two tags that cover the same thing, but the terms are so different it's hard to see how one tag would fit both usages.

Comment: I think it should be synonymized to our existing [code-compliance] tag, even -- they're two different terms for the same basic function.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - If you put an answer in the answer box, people can vote on it.

Comment: I think a better question is, do we need location specific tags? Narrowing one tag down to one country would be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

> I think it should be synonymized to our existing [code-compliance] tag, even -- they're two different terms for the same basic function. – *ThreePhaseEel*